# Why do we need pure silicon for a solar cell to be efficient?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

Why is it that we need ~99% pure silicon in order to have efficient solar cells? I understand that as silicon purity decreases so does solar cell efficiency but I'd like to understand why.

Comment: I suppose purity needs to be quite a bit higher than that to create a $pn$-junction.

Comment: I’m device grade silicon, dopants are in the parts per million range. Random crud at higher levels is Bad with a capital B. (Well, carbon and oxygen have their own reasons and uses).

Answer (score 2):

**Impurities increase recombination rate and will reduce efficiency of the solar cell.**

A high-efficiency silicon solar cell has quite a thick p-doped region,

[image: silicon solar cell]

This is required because to achieve decent optical absorption; silicon has quite a low absorption coefficient in the visible and near infrared.

Fortunately, the **diffusion length** of photo-generated minority carries in **high-quality** silicon is very long.

The cell is designed to balance these competing processes: a thick cell increases the number of solar photons absorbed (increasing efficiency), but making it too thick, above the diffusion length, will cause an increase in recombination and decrease efficiency.

If the silicon is not highly pure this delicate balance will be disrupted. An electron (minority carrier) diffusing in the p-region will recombine, by interaction with an impurity, **before** is can diffuse across the junction and be collected.

Answer (score 0):

for a piece of Si to behave as a semiconductor requires there be almost no other elements in solid solution within it except for the dopants; otherwise the junction structures will not function properly.

Comment: you are right, will edit. -NN

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that can contribute to this behavior. But the most important is that we use Silicon because it is an indirect band gap material, which means that electrons need to change their momentum as well as their energy to recombine with a hole; this allows electrons and holes (minor carriers) to move long distances from depletion region to the contacts. In a Silicon sample with impurities or lattice imperfections, according to the localization of electrons (and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle), the required momentum for the recombination process is supplied and efficiency decreases (as if the number of generated e-h pairs were less).

M.M.