# Is it possible to relate the usage of types silicon in a solar cell to a phase diagram of doped Silicon? (Si-P, Si-B)

Tags: solar-cells, phase-diagram

With reading this post ([Why do we need pure silicon for a solar cell to be efficient?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/576590/why-do-we-need-pure-silicon-for-a-solar-cell-to-be-efficient)) I am seeing these new concepts I never thought were in a solar cell. With bare minimum google searches I thought the usage of silicon in solar cells was with 99.99% purity only, however this post is helping me start to comprehend what p-doped and N-doped entails and why we utilize these in solar cells.

I was wondering why we utilize these doped reigons and if its possible to relate these concepts to a phase diagram and the structures generated.